# Libgdx and android studio

Tags: java, libgdx, apache-commons-compress

EDIT: I fixed it, the problem was that I was not using the same android api and sdks as the ones used by libgdx.

I am trying to build my first libgdx project on android studio but I get an error:

`A build operation failed. 'void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel)' 'void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel)'`

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wenS8.png)

I am using the latest version of android studio, the latest libgdx setup tool and jdk 18.

The following is my build.gradle file

`buildscript {

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.wisepersist:gwt-gradle-plugin:1.1.16'
    classpath 'org.gretty:gretty:3.0.7'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
    classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.16'
    

}
```

}

allprojects {
apply plugin: "eclipse"

```
version = '1.0'
ext {
    appName = "JumpMaster"
    gdxVersion = '1.11.0'
    roboVMVersion = '2.3.16'
    box2DLightsVersion = '1.5'
    ashleyVersion = '1.7.4'
    aiVersion = '1.8.2'
    gdxControllersVersion = '2.2.1'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

}

project(":desktop") {
apply plugin: "java-library"

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":core")
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl3:$gdxVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx-controllers:gdx-controllers-desktop:$gdxControllersVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    
}
```

}

project(":android") {
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

```
configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    implementation project(":core")
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    api "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx-controllers:gdx-controllers-android:$gdxControllersVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    
}
```

}

project(":ios") {
apply plugin: "java-library"
apply plugin: "robovm"

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":core")
    api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
    api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx-controllers:gdx-controllers-ios:$gdxControllersVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    
}
```

}

project(":html") {
apply plugin: "java-library"
apply plugin: "gwt"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "org.gretty"

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":core")
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
    api "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion:sources"
    api "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion:sources"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion:sources"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx-controllers:gdx-controllers-core:$gdxControllersVersion:sources"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx-controllers:gdx-controllers-gwt:$gdxControllersVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx-controllers:gdx-controllers-gwt:$gdxControllersVersion:sources"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion:sources"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
    
}
```

}

project(":core") {
apply plugin: "java-library"

```
dependencies {
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx-controllers:gdx-controllers-core:$gdxControllersVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    
}
```

}
`

I tried rebuilding it several times and making new projects but for some reason my project won't build in android studio. I even tried in IntelliJ Idea but that didn't work either (im pretty sure that's because android studio is built off of intellij idea).

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: It's related to the Gradle build tools version, but that's all I've managed to establish so far. I get the same issue with 7.2.2.

Comment: Reverting back to 4.2.0 resolves the issue, but this obviously doesn't explain the cause and isn't a long term fix.